# Round-trip transit through Canada: does it double transit visa costs?

Tags: visas, transit, budget, canada, transit-visas

I am a Romanian passport holder and will be transiting through Canada both ways during a round trip travel between US <-> China.  (This is necessary if want to take an affordable Air Canada flight.)  To be able to transit, I need to get a Canadian visa.

Question: will I need two transit visas, which effectively double the cost?  Is it possible to get a multiple entry *transit* visa?

There will be 31 days between the two trips.

---

After a lot of searching, I am unable to find this information on [the official website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/index.asp).  There are multiple entry visas, but it's not clear if there are multiple entry *transit* visas, and it's also not clear how much time can pass between the two entries.  I am unable to find any contact information (email or phone number) where I can inquire about this.  I need to know how much the visas cost to be able to make a decision about which flight to take.

Comment: What's your citizenship?  What's your transit point in Canada?  Are you flying out on the same day?

Comment: @Karlson Romanian. Vancouver.  Yes, during business hours (single flight ticket).  [My related question.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30518/1293)

Comment: what flights are you taking? There were (and perhaps still are) some China flights that transit in YYZ without going landside or needing transit visas.

Comment: Are you by chance a US Green Card holder?

Comment: @KateGregory Information for airlines doesn't make this distinction for Romanian citizens. https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=RO&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CN&EM=US&TR=CA&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#

Comment: I thought that transit VISA is free: http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/turkey-turquie/visas/Transit.aspx?lang=eng

Comment: @Karlson I've already determined that I do need a visa (i.e. I'm not a green card holder).  Thanks for that link, it's very useful.  I was under the impression that it costs C$100.  It is indeed mentioned [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=420&t=16) as well that there's no fee for a transit visa.  I'll accept this if you past as answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs Not really an answer since I can't determine the necessity of another visa for the return leg.

Comment: @Karlson But I did mention that I need the information for budget reasons, so it's clear that it does solve my problem.  Also, the title was: "does it double transit visa costs?"  Since 1*0=2*0, it doesn't, regardless of the number of visas needed.  :-)

Comment: @Karlson If you don't post an answer I'm going to do it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok.  You convinced me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned on several pages for Canadian Embassies for ([Jamaica](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/jamaica-jamaique/visas/fees-frais.aspx), and [Turkey](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/turkey-turquie/visas/Transit.aspx?lang=eng)) the transit visa is Free so the cost is:

2 x nothing = nothing

> Transit Visa (for less than 48 hours in Canada) -- free

The only thing I wasn't able to find is whether you will be able to get away with a single transit visa for both parts of the journey.