# If you're not leaving the transit lounge, do you need a visa?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, layovers

In airports around the world, if you are in transit/layover, and you don't leave the transit lounge, do you still need a transit visa?

I am asking to clarify as a concept and not to a specific place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now these rules depend very much on several individual factors such as your passport, your destination and the transit point, even the airline you are flying, but as a general rule of thumb:

**If you do need a visa to transit in a country then you need it also when not leaving the airside transit area.**

Actually in many places you do require a regular visitor visa to go landside, and be it only for five minutes to catch some fresh air.

Comment: Are you sure you really mean the bold sentence? I've done a few tests using [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y), and it is really easy to find cases for which a visa is required if, and only if, the passenger is going to go through immigration control.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan care to post an example? Are the visa you refer to still transit visa? (I.e. national is good to transit w/o visa but not for a visit). Then transit can often be landside, e.g. in China. The truth is the Q is too broad and I should not have answered.

Comment: Example: Afghan citizen, with a visa for the USA, traveling somewhere other than the USA.

Comment: I do agree that the question is too broad. Even narrowed down to connections at UK airports there are many different cases.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I see better now. The way I mean the bold sentence is: "If you do need a transit visa, you also need it when staying airside." In the example you give no transit visa is needed to start with.

Comment: In the example, a transit visa is needed to pass border control. It is not needed to stay airside.